# goroutine race condition solution

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm trying to understand how can I fix this race condition for below code.

```
sayHello := func() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from goroutine")
}

go sayHello()
time.Sleep(1)

fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
```

**Expectation**: I just want to know whats the best solution, should I use WaitGroup or is there any better solution ?

So I came up with below solution :

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
//defer wg.Wait()
sayHello := func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("Hello from goroutine")
}
wg.Add(1)

go sayHello()
wg.Wait()

fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
```

But its blocking the main goroutine until code is executed !

As well, if I use `defer wg.Wait()` the output is different ! https://play.golang.org/p/_xkLb7HvNF8

Race condition I meant where `go sayHello()` never even gets executed, cause the main func will finish executing before the goroutine even started. Hence it creates a race condition if I try to put a time.Sleep

Comment: What's the race condition? You want the print from the goroutine to display before the print from main?

Comment: I don't see a race condition.

Comment: race condition I meant where `go sayHellow()` never even gets executed, cause the main func will finish executing before the goroutine even started. Hence it creates a race condition if I try to put a time.Sleep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no a [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34510/9811969) in your code.

**First question**

> But its blocking the main goroutine until code is executed !

You are using right after the `sayHello` call:

```
wg.Wait()
```

This blocks your code and waits until the goroutine will be executed. So, `go sayHello()` will print `"Hello from goroutine"` always before `"Hello, playground"`.

See documentation [here](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup.Wait):

> Wait blocks until the WaitGroup counter is zero.

**Second question**

> As well, if I use defer wg.Wait() the output is different !

Yes, in this case `wg.Wait()` will be executed before exit the main function. This means `sayHello()` will print `"Hello from goroutine"` before **or** after `"Hello, playground"` - this depends on *Go scheduler*

See more about `defer` [here](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover)

> A defer statement pushes a function call onto a list. The list of saved calls is executed after the surrounding function returns. Defer is commonly used to simplify functions that perform various clean-up actions.

**Update:**

Using `WaitGroup` is recommended in comparison to another solution using channels. You should use `wg.Wait()` at the right place to achieve the expected output (still not provided).

Comment: thanks. Also can you suggest what would be the best code for the same ? I mean how do I fix it

Comment: Could you extend your question with expected output?

Comment: Using WaitGroup is the best. See here a comparison of two solutions: WaitGroup vs channels https://stackoverflow.com/q/36056615/9811969